# Mongoldb over http via nginx (stream) reverse proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am wanting to move a hosted mongo database service to a self hosted solution, behind a firewall.  The hosted ruby on rails app connects via MongoMapper.  I want to port only the database first, and then maybe the ruby on rails app.

I've set up server_name `data.example.com` port 80 on nginx 1.9.11 to redirected to another upstream port, `localhost:8090`.

This is done as I also have this nginx serve a website `example.com:80` and `www.example.com:80`, but I only want `data.example.com:80` to connect to the upstream tcp port. I do this as server_name is http section only, i.e. understandably not available in the stream server set-up)

so the `"data-web-domain":80` to `localhost:8090` config:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name data.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8090;
}
```

Now I then pass `localhost:8090` to mongodb via stream to allow tcp connection.

```
stream {
    server {
        listen                8090;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1s;
        proxy_timeout 3s;
        proxy_pass    stream_mongo_backend;
      }
      upstream stream_mongo_backend {
          server localhost:27017;
      }
 }
```

and can browse to as data.example.com

> Blockquote 
>   You are trying to access MongoDB on the native driver port. For http diagnostic access, add 1000 to the port number

Ok so the above config allows a web request at the web domain to return an error message back from the mongodb

When connecting to the server directly, via localhost or the server's unix domain name to the port 8090 the stream redirect to 27017 works, i.e. this mongo command line connects

```
mongo server-unix-name:8090/dummydb -udummyuser -pdummysecret
```

But via the web domain doesn't

```
mongo data.example.com:80/dummydb -udummyuser -pdummysecret
```

What's broken between the `data.example.com:80` to the `localhost:8090`?

Comment: `doesn't`? Doesn't how? What error comes up? I'm using a similar setup and going through nginx via local terminal works

Comment: @Rexford in the end i ported everything over in one go. Maybe I should delete my question?

Comment: How did you do the porting? What did the porting involve?

Comment: For the DB - Dump the contents of the hosted mongodb to local disc, import it to mongodb, create mongo user. For the app - install ruby, clone the repo, install the app (gem file) change the app config to point to new mongodb, and new user. Start rails app